# How to use one return for a data type to return an error?

Tags: c++, struct, return

I have code that uses a struct as the return type. I want to return a null instance of the struct as an error, but return the dereference version of the struct when not an error. How can I do this using only one return in the entire function? Yes, it is very easy to use two return, but I need to only use one return.

Comment: it would be better if you add an example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

> **”** return a null instance of the struct as an error, but return the dereference version of the struct when not an error.

```
return (is_error? S() : *pointer_to_struct);
```

If by **null instance** you do not mean a default initialized one, then you can use a C++17 `std::optional`, or a `boost::optional` (from the Boost library). Or you can roll your own quick and dirty `Optional`. When you can disregard efficiency it's not hard at all:

```
template< class Wrapped >
class Optional
{
private:
    vector<Wrapped> data_;
public:
    auto is_empty() const -> bool { return data_.empty(); }

    auto ref() -> Wrapped& { return data_.at( 0 ); }
    auto ref() const -> Wrapped const& { return data_.at( 0 ); }

    Optional() {}

    Optional( Wrapped value ) { data_.push_back( move( value ) ); }
};
```

Disclaimer: code not touched by compiler's hands.

Comment: I am new to programming. Is is_error a c++ built in macro? If so what header is it in? Thanks!

Comment: @teenHere: No, it's not a built-in. It's just an example.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do this using only one return in the entire function?

You can use [std::optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) since C++17 (or [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)), e.g.

```
std::optional<some_struct> foo() {
    if (...)
        return something;
    else // error
        return {};
}
```

then

```
if (auto result = foo()) {
    // use result.value() to get some_struct
    // ...
} else {
    // error
}
```

Comment: At lower than `std::c++17`, you can use [`boost::qptional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) (header only lib).